# Need to update attributes to database multiple times in ruby on rails in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

For a reason i need to run update the database table many times . I wrote the logic in a while loop. So that , untill the array length is reached , it updates different values of attributes to database.

```
if request.post?
  @user_new = Bookmark.new(params[:user_new])
  tags = @user_new.tags.split(",")
  i=0
  while i<tags.length
    @user_new.update_attributes(:title => @user_new.title, :url => @user_new.url, :tags => i)  
    i=i+1
  end
```

But it doesnt seem so.

Only the last update statement is been executed. Why is it?

How can i run mulitple update statements in accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

The column of your table would be updated `i` times, so the final value would be the `tags.length`. It isn't updating only the last one, but all of them in order.

Comment: I thought the same and wrote the code. But only the last one is getting executed